# Adding object fields to @Query

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

In the request, an object is passed as an argument. How can I pass the fields of this object to the request? 
Thanks to all.

```
@Repository
public interface DevelopersRepository extends CrudRepository<Developers, Integer> , DevelopersDao {

    /**
     * Update developer.
     *
     * @param developer developer.
     * @return number of updated records in the database.
     */
    @Query(value="UPDATE developers SET firstName=:firstName, lastName = :lastName WHERE developerId = :developerId",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Integer update (Developers developer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `@Param`. I would also recommend changing the column names in the database as they currently don't fit the conventions. "firstName" should be "first_name" and so on.

`Integer update (@Param("firstName") String firstName, @Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("developerId") Integer developerId);`

**EDIT** If you want to keep the method arguments as they are you could use:

```
@Query(value="UPDATE developers SET firstName = :developer.firstName, lastName = :developer.lastName WHERE developerId = :developer.developerId",
            nativeQuery = true)
Integer update (@Param("developer") Developers developer);
```

`developer.developerId` may need to be changed to `developer.id` depending on how you named it in your entity class.

Comment: I need to pass exactly the object.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem

```
@Modifying
    @Query(value="INSERT INTO developers (firstName, lastName) VALUES (:#{#dev.firstName}, :#{#dev.lastName})",
            nativeQuery = true)
    Integer create(@Param("dev")Developers developer);
```